# Prove and Find the solution.

Tags: analysis

$1)$ Prove that there is a unique strictly positive solution $0 <p < 1$,which satisfies the equation : $x^n + x - 1 = 0$

$2)$ Find the limit of $p$ as $n$ tends to $+∞$

As suggested by the com's:

I had  $n\ln(x)=\ln(1-x)$ so I plotted a graph of $\ln(x)$ and $\ln(1-x)$. I realised that the graph of $\ln(x)$ is strictly increasing in the interval $0≤p<1$ while that of $\ln(1-x)$ is strictly decreasing, thus so would the graph of $n\ln(1-x)$ as a result they would only meet once. I think some how I solved the first part but the second is ambiguous i was thinking of continued fractions and Evariste Galois but it ended in nothingness.

Comment: What have you tried? Demanding answers without any discussion on the problems is a likely way to have your question closed and unanswered. You may wish to edit your post to include additional relevant information.

Comment: The reason I don't put any comments is because I don't want to influence anyone with a particular way of reasoning and let every one express his or her mathematical thinking independently.Note :if you had a solution I'm pretty sure you would have posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a)$: Consider $f_n(x) = x^n + x - 1$ on $(0,1)$. $f_n(0) = - 1 < 0, f_n(1) = 1 > 0$,and $f_n(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, thus by the Mean Value Theorem, there is a root in $(0,1)$ of $f_n(x)$ for each $n \geq 1$.Also $f_n'(x) = nx^{n-1} + 1 > 0$, thus $f_n(x)$ is strictly increasing over $(0,1)$, and thus has only one real root over there.

$b)$. Using Bernoulli inequality we have: $p^n + p - 1 = 0 \Rightarrow 0 < p = \left(1-p\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq 1 - \dfrac{p}{n} \Rightarrow 0 < p < \dfrac{n}{n+1} \Rightarrow p \to 1$, by taking limit $n \to \infty$

Comment: $0 < p < \dfrac{n}{n+1}$ does this provide that $p \to 1$?